# How to integrate new Google map app with ios app

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

[Google Map](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8) is now available in Appstore for IOS 6. I have a application which utilises MAPKIT and WebView to show Driving direction using Google webservices.
For showing Route in Native Apple MAP app, i use codes similar to this..

```
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];
NSDictionary *options = @{
MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
};
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

I want to show Route to the user in the New Google MaP App installed on user device, embeed its UI within a View in my app.

Do guide me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goole have released latest API for IOS 6.0 and up.

For that follow the step below

1. You have to registered your app and get the keys from [Map IOS access](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access).
2. Refer the following link for further detail
   [New way to add google maps in iOS 6 app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)

Comment: how did you follow the steps? i applied for API key access at console and no response yet, other than that, as given in the steps, where did you find the "Google Maps SDK for iOS" to enable it in the services.

Comment: please read and download https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: friend, i did follow it, an had registered for access, but no response yet from google!..moreover, in the steps under "obtaining API key", while creating an api project, i can't see any service named "Google Maps SDK for iOS" as they suggest, will you please try it and reply me?

Comment: @ibiren what is there to check? Am already talking about that link dude, Still I did't see "Google Maps SDK for iOS"  in those! U saw??

Answer (score 5):

For displaying the directions within the GoogleMaps app, using the new GoogleMaps URL scheme along the lines of:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit
```

Taken from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) should help you. A short browse from there, you will also notice that Google have released an SDK for the new GoogleMaps, with access tokens being rolled out slowly. Doc

- seemed to cut off the end of my answer, but @Hi Ren has filled in the end with the link to the documentation to the new [SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro).

Comment: is it backward compatible ? Means can ios 6 sdk google map code could also work in lower versions of IOS Google app ?

Comment: no it's work for ios 6.0 and later version you have to put condition according your version.check out the documentation->Introduction->supported platforms