# Google maps in xcode for directions

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

In TableView I have a "Directions" button and when it is clicked then Google maps should open with the corresponding url .I need to load GoogleMaps on a WebView.But I couldnot get the webView loaded with it .

```
ViewController.h:

@property(nonatomic,retain)BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView *businessNearbyLocationMapView;

In ViewController.m:
@synthesize businessNearbyLocationMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ic_launcher.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    imageView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,120,50);
    [self.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,70)];
    self.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
-(IBAction)showDirections:(id)sender
{
     selectedRow=[sender tag];
    NSMutableDictionary * location = [[[places objectAtIndex:selectedRow]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString * lat = [location objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString * lng = [location objectForKey:@"lng"];

    AppAppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    businessNearbyLocationMapView.url =@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@,%@",appDelegate.userlatitude,appDelegate.userlongitude,lat,lng;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.businessNearbyLocationMapView animated:YES];
}

BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView.m:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString *fullUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@", self.url];
    NSURL *aboutURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fullUrl];
    [fullUrl release];
    [viewWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aboutURL]];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

But I couldn't see the webview loaded with corresponding url? Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Question not related to an XCode feature/issue. XCode tag removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying the directions within the GoogleMaps app, using the new GoogleMaps URL scheme along the lines of:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit
```

1. Check out this document here [URl Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

You can also check out the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879211/how-to-integrate-new-google-map-app-with-ios-app/13879366#13879366)

Comment: Prevoiusly I got Googlemaps with that url when I took a mapview in a UIViewController and displayed.But I need to display it in a WebView now becoz I need to have  back button that returns from googlemaps to my app,which is possible when I take a webView

Comment: please check your url proper. please NSlog and open it in safari if it's open in safari then it's work perfect in your app

Comment: have you check your URL in BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView ?  why you are release URL before load ? what have you done in your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I didnot do anything for viewDdLoad

Comment: can you post your targeturl?

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=37.785834,-122.406417&daddr=37.789632,-122.417004

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21671/discussion-between-hi-ren-and-sindhia)

Answer (score 0):

just use self.url not add `http://` before this url..it is already attach in the `self.url` variable...For Example use like bellow..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        viewWebView.delegate=self;
        NSString *fullUrl =  self.url;
        fullUrl = [self removeNull:fullUrl];
        [fullUrl retain];
        NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullUrl];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [viewWebView loadRequest:request];
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and add this two methods in your `BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView.m` file..

```
-(NSString*) trimString:(NSString *)theString {
    NSString *theStringTrimmed = [theString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    return theStringTrimmed;
}

-(NSString *) removeNull:(NSString *) string {    

    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"null"];
    //NSLog(@"in removeNull : %d  >>>> %@",range.length, string);
    if (range.length > 0 || string == nil) {
        string = @"";
    }
    string = [self trimString:string];
    return string;
}
```

This above two methods are my custom method which through we remove the `null` or space from string, its problem may be because in url somewhere space or null values gone so...

**UPDATE:**

```
-(IBAction)showDirections:(id)sender
{
     selectedRow=[sender tag];
    NSMutableDictionary * location = [[[places objectAtIndex:selectedRow]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString * lat = [location objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString * lng = [location objectForKey:@"lng"];

    AppAppDelegate  *appDelegate=(AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView *newbusinessNearbyLocationMapView =[[BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView alloc]initWithNibName:@"BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView" bundle:nil];
    newbusinessNearbyLocationMapView.url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@,%@",appDelegate.userlatitude,appDelegate.userlongitude,lat,lng];
    [newbusinessNearbyLocationMapView.url retain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newbusinessNearbyLocationMapView animated:YES];
    [newbusinessNearbyLocationMapView relese];

}
```

hope this helpful to you...

Comment: @Paras.Did as u said.But my problem is it is not entering BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView.m.I think  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.businessNearbyLocationMapView animated:YES]; is not responding.Can u please tell me how to create a NavigationController in a ViewController not in appdelegate.I have directly added it in .xib file and didnot link anywhere

Comment: Im confused where should I create navigation controller and how do I connect it to .xib

Comment: @Sindhia just see, i create code for push in your new class with xib so use my code with your method ok.. just comment your code and use my code and then try it..

Comment: used it.but couldnot get it.I have to create it in ViewController should I need to connect anything in .xib because I have created a UINavigation controller like this : in .h @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController; in .m :@synthesize navigationController;

Comment: hey but see what you want that is your url open in webview in your this class so here now i also update the new data use this , you not store the url with format so i think this is the problem and you want the navigationbar in your BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView class??

Comment: see I have used the same as u said but still couldnot get it.Yes I need the navigationbar in BusinessNearbyLocationsMapView becoz I need to have a back button in it bcoz directly we cannot keep back button in googlemaps page so

Comment: just post your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, i just want to check that its navigation based app or not so...

Comment: no it is not navigation based app.It is a tabbar based app.So I want to create navigationcontroller in UIViewController directly and use it.I m not gettting it

Comment: oh then see you can add navigationbar like this.. UINavigationController *navNearMe=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objNearMeView]; and add this navNewMe in tabbar like self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navNewMe,etc, nil];

Comment: no Paras its not like that .bcoz I dont want a navigation controller on app start up.I m having a separate ViewController which loads when a button is clicked and in that I have a Directions button which when pressed should redirect to WebView showing map and navigation bar with back button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21672/discussion-between-sindhia-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: @Sindhia wait after half hour i give the response and just hide the navigationbar in first view and show it in your another class its very simple dude.. :)

Comment: @Sindhia i am on chatroom dude...come there